# SLICC indexing syntax

Tags: gem5

I have been digging through the cache-related parts of Gem5 (particularly the parts related to directories), and I've hit a bit of a snag.

This is the code for `getDirectoryEntry(Addr addr)`, in src/mem/ruby/protocol/MESI_Two_Level-dir.sm:

```
  Entry getDirectoryEntry(Addr addr), return_by_pointer="yes" {
    Entry dir_entry := static_cast(Entry, "pointer", directory[addr]);

    if (is_valid(dir_entry)) {
      return dir_entry;
    }

    dir_entry :=  static_cast(Entry, "pointer",
                              directory.allocate(addr, new Entry));
    return dir_entry;
  }
```

Note the first line inside the function, where it says `directory[addr]`.

`directory` was previously defined like so:

```
machine(MachineType:Directory, "MESI Two Level directory protocol")
 : DirectoryMemory * directory;
...
```

I am trying to understand exactly what that `directory[addr]` bit of code means. Intuitively, it may be calling the C++ `DirectoryMemory::lookup(Addr address)` method, but I haven't found any code or documentation that supports that guess.

The `DirectoryMemory` class doesn't define an indexing operator, and there's also nothing [in the SLICC page on the wiki](http://gem5.org/SLICC#Special_Functions) that describes an indexing operator.

tl;dr: what does the indexing operator mean in SLICC? It it's defined for particular objects somewhere in the SLICC code, what should I be looking for to find its definition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself. It calls the `lookup` method in DirectoryMemory, as I suspected.